# Parent position:absolute and children z-index

Tags: css, position, z-index, absolute

I want to have higher z-index for childrens .bricks so they could always overlap other parents (red square). Parent has to be positioned absolute.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/yJ62e/

html

```
<div class="cont">
<div class="draggable" id="b2">
<div class="brick"></div>
<div class="brick"></div>
<div class="brick"></div>
</div>
<div class="draggable" id="b2">
<div class="brick"></div>
<div class="brick"></div>
<div class="brick"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

css

```
    .cont {
    position:relative;
background-color: #747373;
height: 300px;
width: 300px;
margin:0 auto;
    }
.draggable {
    background-color: red;
right:100px;
cursor:pointer;
z-index:1;
position:absolute;
}

    #b2 {
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
}

.brick {
     background-color: blue;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
float: left;
z-index:999 !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I can think of would be to position the .brick-Children absolute as well. Otherwise z-index won't work.

Comment: Thanks for answer but it doesn't fix my problem. Updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/yJ62e/2/

Comment: try and remove `z-index:1;` from `.draggable`